# How to grid search the class_weight of SVM by using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I'm now using scikit learn to tune parameters of SVM binary classifier. There are three parameters: `gamma` (for RBF), `weight+1` and `weight-1` for each class (C=1). In scikit learn, the `class_weight` option is provided.

Now, I want to perform grid search for parameters. But I don't know whether scikit learn support such tunig problem. Assume that `weight+1: 1--10, weight-1: 1--10`, who can show me how to write? Thank you very much.

Comment: Same as the other parameters. I don't see the problem.